# LDA Gensim Mallet setting alpha as 'auto'

Tags: python, gensim, lda

I am using LDA for Topic Modelling in Python.Gensim implementation of LDA allows us to set alpha as 'auto' as below:

```
alpha ({numpy.ndarray, str}, optional) –
    
            ’asymmetric’: Uses a fixed normalized asymmetric prior of 1.0 / topicno.
    
            ’auto’: Learns an asymmetric prior from the corpus (not available if distributed==True).
```

For LDA Mallet wrapper provided in Gensim there is no option of setting alpha as auto.

Is there way to learn alpha from the corpus in LDA Mallet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is in the `optimize_interval` argument. From the [wrapper documentation](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/wrappers/ldamallet.html):

> optimize_interval (int, optional) – Optimize hyperparameters every optimize_interval iterations

So although alpha is originally set (or left as the default), if you set `optimize_interval` then every n iterations, the alpha and beta will be optimised automatically.